# How do I loop through Matrix data how it appears?

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision

**Situation**

I have a matrix which is 300 columns and 1 row. When I `cout <<` it, I get:

```
[  0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0]
```

...which is of the form I expect/want.

**Problem**

However, when I loop through it, I want to get each single value each iteration. However, instead I get a slightly different order (sometimes it is quite similar, though).

**Code**

```
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgcodecs/imgcodecs.hpp"

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main(){


  Mat test(1,300,CV_8UC1, 255);
    cout << test;

    Mat frame, grayFrame,threshFrame,smaller;

    VideoCapture cap(0);

    while(true){
        cap.read(frame);
        cvtColor(frame, grayFrame, cv::COLOR_RGB2GRAY);
        threshold(grayFrame, threshFrame, 160, 255, THRESH_BINARY);
        smaller = threshFrame(Rect(0,0,300,1));
        cout << smaller;

        for(int x=0;x<smaller.cols;x++){
            int color = smaller.at<Vec3b>(x,1)[0];
            cout << color;

        }

        break;        
    }

}
```

... And the weird output that does not follow the exact same order of 0s and 255s as the original Matrix:

```
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002552552552552552552552552552552552552552552552552552552552552552552552552552552552552552552552552552552552552552552552552552552552552552552552552552552552552552552552552552552552552552552552552552552552552552552552552552552552552552552550000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

The matrix has many 0s at first, and few 255s, where as the loop output has many 255s, and not so much beginning 0s.

Essentially, I want to loop through the matrix first shown, and for each iteration, get each value. So 0,0,255,255... etc.

Comment: you're not printing spaces between your values...

Comment: my problem has nothing to do with the spaces, data structure. one is an array one is a int output...i mean the ORDER. you will notice the order is still different, original starts "0,0,255" and loop starts "255,255,255"

Comment: so it is. Would you provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: How shall I make it more simple? I have a basic, single channel matrix. Once I loop through it, it comes out different. How would you loop through it? I must be doing something wrong. Huge thanks.

Comment: Which word is tripping you up? Minimal, Complete, or Verifiable?

Comment: Don't just use `cv::Vec3b` because it seems correct. What's `Matrix`'s type?

Comment: Do you mind telling me how you would want my question improved instead of stating three words which I believe my question already meets - what is confusing you? cheers

Comment: the type is CV_8UC1 - hence why I know uchar should be what i use...hwover the output is extremely odd (/377/3777).

Comment: In that case you need `unsigned char` and not `cv::Vec3b`

Comment: Can we have a complete program of minimal size which compiles and verifiably demonstrates this behavior?

Comment: Well your post is _minimal_ but not complete or verifiable. Or do you expect us to implement `main`, initializing the matrix, then run it through the couple of lines of code you supplied?

Comment: Okay. Give me a sec. cheers

Comment: We need to see how you initiate `Matrix`'s values

Comment: ok. updated. check it out. cheers

Comment: change `int color = smaller.at<Vec3b>(x,1)[0];` to `int color = smaller.at<unsigned char>(0,x);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're reading garbage.

- The `at` function needs `(row, col)`, and not `(x, y)`. Remember that `row = y`, and `col = x`.
- If your matrix is just a single row, the row index must be `0`, not `1`.
- Your matrix is a single channel of unsigned char, so you need to use `at<uchar>`

In practice, use:

```
uchar color = smaller.at<uchar>(0, x);
cout << int(color);
```

or using indices:

```
uchar color = smaller.at<uchar>(x);
```